# Why Don't Ashkenasim say ברכו at the end of Shabbos Mussaf?

Tags: shabbat, tefilla, blessing, musaf

I noticed that while Sephardim do in fact say: ברכו את ה המבורך at the conclusion of Mussaf on Shabbos, it seems that Ashkenasim (at least the shuls that I go to) don't. Is there a reason for this?

*A side point: These same Ashkenasi shuls do say it at the conclusion of the Weekday Shacharis prayers.*

Answer (score 1):

2 answers, based on asking people the same question:

**1:** Many Ashkenazi shuls do **not** say ברכו at the conclusion of the Weekday Shacharis prayers on **Mondays and Thursdays** or Rosh Chodesh.

They (apparently the Talmidei haGro) *borrowed* the *ברכו at the end of Shabbos Shacharis* from the Sefardim, in case somebody came late.

But on days when there is Krias haTorah, the latecomers will already have heard ברכו, so there's no need to add it.

**2:** Many Ashkenazi shuls have adopted various Minhagim in order to accommodate people with various Mihagim. (I.e Sefardim, Teimanim and Chasidim.)

Included are ברכו at the end and saying the י"ג מידות before Tachanun, at least on Mondays and Thursdays.

But on Shabbat they keep to the original Nusach Ashkenaz.

Comment: but there are shuls where don't say borchu at all at the end of services, perhaps people coming on time? :)